# Ruby, unexplainable reduce behavior

Tags: ruby, reduce

Good day. The common practice in solving a kind of **'find unique value'** problems at different programming competitions is using this code `arr.reduce(:^)`:

For example tasks  like this **You are given an odd-length array of integers, in which all of them are the same, except for one single number. Find this number**  Usually solved this way: 
`[8,8,8,5,8,8,8].reduce(:^) # 5`

I start to make experiments and found one gap this this solution, here it is:

```
p [8,2,2].reduce(:^) # 8
p [8,2,2,2].reduce(:^) # 10 !!!!!!!!
p [8,2,2,2,2].reduce(:^) # 8
```

I found that in any array format `[x,y,y,y]` the `x` cannot be found by `reduce(:^)`:

```
p x = rand(1..100)
p y = rand(1..100)
p [x, y, y, y].reduce(:^) == x # FALSE (!)
puts "But!"
p [x, y, y ].reduce(:^) == x # true
p [x, y, y, y, y ].reduce(:^) == x # true
```

Why do it happens? (My ruby is MRI 2.3.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You are given an **odd-length** array of integers, ...

How is `[8, 2, 2, 2]` odd-length?

The third `2` is never XOR’ed out. One might check this step by step:

```
8 ^ 2
#⇒ 10
8 ^ 2 ^ 2
#⇒ 8 # because 2 and 2 are XOR’ed out
8 ^ 2 ^ 2 ^ 2
#⇒ 10 # because it’s the same as 8 ^ 2
```

Also:

```
2 ^ 2 ^ 2
#⇒ 2
```

Answer (score 1):

@mudasobwa answer is correct.  However for more insight you might wanna have a a look at:

https://www.calleerlandsson.com/rubys-bitwise-operators/

For your use case you are better off with:

```
[8,2,2,2].inject{|i,n| i > n ? i : n}
```

Let's see what's going on under the hood:

```
def max_array_int(arr)
  arr.inject do |i,n|
    check = i > n ? i : n
    puts "evaluated #{i} > #{n}. result: #{check}"
    check
  end
end

max_array_int [10,3,15,7]
```